# How to run Java class without knowing a class name

Tags: java, program-entry-point, classname

I have a **content** of compiled Java class as a binary file (named `X.class`). Let's assume it has some class inside with a proper `main` method, but I don't know original class name (and it's not `X`).

How can I run it with `java` using **single** command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the name of the class using `javap -c <filename>`. From that point on, it's just shell games. This works on OS X:

```
java $(javap -c File.class | head -n 2 | tail -n1 | cut -f3 -d\ )
```

Note the space after the `\` in the subshell - this is requires to isolate the class name.

Update based on @nikolay-vyahhi feedback: 
If you're not sure at which position the class name will appear (e.g. when it's unknown whether the class is public or not), you can use `tr` and `grep`, like so:

```
java $(javap -c File.class | head -n2| tail -n1 | tr [:space:] \\n | grep -A1 "class\|interface" | tail -n1)
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case the second line after `javap` is `class Secret {`, not `public class Secret {`, so the command `cut -f3 -d\ ` gives just `{`, not `Secret`. Not sure if it's possible to support both cases with the same `cut` arguments.

Comment: Thanks! But it still doesn't work for just `class Secret {` – there is no dot in the class name. Also, `javap -c java.lang.String |  head -n2 | tail -n1 | tr [:space:] \\n | grep \\.` outputs four (!) lines, because classes can `implements` and `extends` other classes and it's in their signature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javap to do that:

```
javap X.class
```

It will disassemble the class and print out the package, protected, and public fields and methods:

```
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  public Test();
  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
}
```

Then you can use this to run the application:

```
java $(javap X.class | sed -n 's/.*class \(.*\) {/\1/p')
```